# Viewport meta tag doesn't work, website renders with zoom-out on mobil

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, viewport

So, I'm adding some responsive stuff to a website, and usually this is no problem, but for some reason the page renders zoomed (at 0.3) when refreshing. All the CSS-changes are implemented, it's just the initial zoom that's wierd.

I use this in my `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

and the responsive stuff is within this tag:

```
    @media screen and (max-device-width: 767px) {
    /*responsive stuff that works*/
    }
```

The page is if you want to have a look yourself: http://utt.se
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

Try delete all commas from `<meta>` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1.0 minimum-scale=1.0 user-scalable=no" />
```

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your site I see that `.blogContent` has a width set on it, as does `#mainContent`.

Changing these to both be `width: 100%` seemed to fix it on chrome for me

Comment: This was fixed, however I had an object with class ´.blogScroll´ that messed things up, so you got me on the right track! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also put zoom viewport property  within css

```
@viewport{
    zoom: 1.0;
    width: extend-to-zoom;
}
```

[click here for more information about viewport zoom](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972)

Answer (score 0):

You should also replace width values to max-width

Replace this

```
.contentCon ul li {
  width: 340px;
```

for this

```
.contentCon ul li {
  max-width: 340px;
```

Comment: That could be a good idea (This is in the responsive CSS-file right?)

Comment: nup, its in style.css